# Проверка условий для следующий элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток. Вот столкнулся с такой задачей. <br/>
У меня 4 DIV-a. Не выбрав первый див нельзя перейти к следующему.Все идет поочередно. <br/>
Выбрав 1й див чтобы все остальные  были не активными, я добавил class='enabled' если есть этот класс то выполнять определенные действия.  <br/>

Проблема в том что я добавляю class для того чтобы следующая кнопка стала активной, класс добавляется только меню чего то не всплывает.!!!!!!

В чем проблема,в чем я провинился !!!!?

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.leftCol div.enabled').click(function(){
                   $(this).addClass('active'); //сделать кнопку активной 
                   $("#"+$(this).attr('arrow')).show(); // Всплывавшее меню 
// Если курсор вышел за пределами всплывающего дива, див закрывается
                       $('.choiceOfDishes').mouseleave(function(){  
                                  $('.choiceOfDishes').hide();
                        }); 
             });
        $('.dish').click(function(){
   Cufon.replace($('.leftCol .active .text').text($(this).text()));
  $("div[arrow="+$(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+"]").next().addClass('enabled');
                //alert($('.dish').parent().parent().attr('id'));
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();

        });
     });
```

Блоки выбора.

```
       <div class="selectionOrder">
            <table class="">
             <tr>
         <td class="leftCol">
   <div class="enabled" arrow="firstArrow"> <div class="text">выберите основу</div></div>
   <div class="" arrow="secondArrow"><div class="text"> добавьте начинку</div></div>
   <div class="" arrow="thirdArrow"><div class="text"> заправьте соусом</div></div>
   <div class="" arrow="fourthArrow"><div class="text"> добавки по вкусу</div></div>
               </td>
```

Выплывающий блоки

```
 <div class="choiceOfDishes" id="firstArrow" >
      <div class="firstArrow"></div> 
          <div class="center">
               <div class="dish">
                 <img  class="imgDish1 "src="/i/1_1.png" />
                 <div>Яичная Лапша</div>
               </div>   
                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="bottomLine"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="choiceOfDishes" id ="secondArrow" >
        <div class="secondArrow"></div>
          <div class="center">
              <div class="dish">
                 <img  class="imgDish1 "src="/i/1_1.png" />
                 <div>Яичная 2</div>
              </div>  
              <div class="dish">
                <img  class="imgDish2 "src="/i/1_2.png" />
                 <div>Яичная 22 </div>
               </div>  
                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="bottomLine"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="choiceOfDishes" id ="thirdArrow">
      <div class="thirdArrow"></div>
          <div class="center">
              <div class="dish">
                 <img  class="imgDish1 "src="/i/1_1.png" />
                 <div>Яичная 3</div>
              </div>   
                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="bottomLine"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="choiceOfDishes" id ="fourthArrow">
      <div class="fourthArrow"></div>
          <div class="center">
              <div class="dish">
                 <img  class="imgDish1 "src="/i/1_1.png" />
                 <div>Яичная 4</div>
              </div>   
                <div class="clear"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="bottomLine"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[Скриншот](http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=db5a31464aa8b17ad446cb81b224a8e8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того, как повесели новый класс на див, к нему надо применять событие не click, а

```
$("ваш див").live("click",function(){
    //Ваше действие
})
```